# How do I buffer a subject such that it emits somewhat like a debounced subject?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I tried using the regular buffer operator that takes a `TimeSpan` as input, but this has a few issues. I only want the buffer to be emitted if these conditions are satisfied:

1. At least one value has been received
2. A set amount of time has passed since the last value was received without receiving any more values

Essentially, I want the buffered subject to behave like this:

1. If the next value is received when the buffer is empty, add the value to the buffer and start a timeout
2. If the next value is received when the buffer is not empty, add the value to the buffer and re-start the timeout
3. Only after the timeout has started and finished, emit the current buffer and start a new buffer

Like a debounced subject, this will only emit when a value has been received, but unlike a debounced subject, it collects all of the values into a buffer instead of discarding them.

I assume I would need a scheduler to accomplish this, and I figured I could copy/reused the debounce operator's scheduler, but I can't find it.

Edit: sorry for the title gore/grammar mistakes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only downside to your answer is that you're creating two separate subscriptions to `MySubject`. If it is dynamically producing values that can cause grief. You should always use a shared subscription.

Here's how:

```
MySubject.Publish(ps => ps.Buffer(() => ps.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))));
```

---

To see the difference using `Publish` makes, try the following code:

```
var rnd = new Random();

var source =
    Observable
        .Generate(
            0, x => x < 100, x => x + 1, x => rnd.Next(10),
            x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(rnd.Next(4)));
```

This generates a series of random numbers between `0` and `9` inclusively at an interval of between `0` and `3` seconds between successive values.

Then, run this query:

```
var query =
    source
        .Publish(ps =>
            ps
                .Do(p => Console.WriteLine($"ps1: {p}"))
                .Buffer(() =>
                    ps
                        .Do(p => Console.WriteLine($"ps2: {p}"))
                        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))));
```

It outputs the following:

```
ps1: 1
ps2: 1
ps1: 2
ps2: 2
ps1: 3
ps2: 3
ps1: 3
ps2: 3
ps1: 6
ps1: 1
ps2: 1
ps1: 3
ps2: 3
ps1: 9
ps1: 5
ps2: 5
ps1: 7
ps2: 7
ps1: 9
ps2: 9
ps1: 1
ps2: 1
ps1: 8
ps2: 8
ps1: 5
ps2: 5
ps1: 6
ps2: 6
...
```

Note that the `ps1` and `ps2` numbers are paired and in sequence - it's always `ps1` then `ps2` before another `ps1`.

The output of the actual observable was this:

```
{ 1, 2, 3 }
{ 3 }
{ 6, 1 }
{ 3 }
{ 9, 5, 7, 9, 1, 8 }
{ 5 }
{ 6 }
```

Now try without the `Publish`:

```
var query =
    source
        .Do(p => Console.WriteLine($"ps1: {p}"))
        .Buffer(() =>
            source
                .Do(p => Console.WriteLine($"ps2: {p}"))
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)));
```

Here's the output:

```
ps1: 0
ps1: 5
ps2: 3
ps1: 6
ps1: 8
ps2: 9
ps1: 7
ps2: 2
ps2: 3
ps2: 4
ps1: 1
ps2: 7
ps2: 4
ps2: 2
ps1: 0
ps1: 6
ps1: 7
ps1: 9
ps1: 2
ps2: 8
ps1: 0
ps2: 3
ps2: 3
ps1: 1
ps2: 9
ps1: 4
ps2: 8
ps2: 3
ps1: 1
...
```

It's now no longer paired nor in sequence.

The output of the observable was this:

```
{ 0, 5, 6, 8 }
{ }
{ 7, 1 }
{ }
{ 0, 6 }
{ 7, 9, 2, 0 }
{ }
{ 1, 4 }
{ }  
...
```

Note the empty buffers!

The results without are not at all reliable.

Always use `Publish` to ensure you're sharing the same source observable.

Comment: Sweet! I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - That overload for `Publish` is the one I use the most. It's excellent to ensure you have a consistent source with just one subscription.

Comment: I would like to better understand the difference here. Checking the ReactiveX docs did not help.. do you have a resource that could better explain the difference/issue that it fixes?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out what to do. Maybe it will help someone else.

```
MySubject
    .Buffer(() => MySubject.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Subscribe(() => ... )
```

Comment: Answering your own question is perfectly acceptable. The purpose of this site is to create a collection of quality questions and answers for future users. Well done!

Comment: The only downside to your answer is that you're creating two separate subscriptions to `MySubject`. If it is dynamically producing values that can cause grief. You should always use a shared subscription. I'll show you how.